# Vertical scroll animation 'jumps' on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm working on a [site](https://ashleyconnor.gitlab.io/adventurersclubcomic/) that uses CSS3 animations.

I've noticed on iOS the comic captions 'jump' which I believe is caused by the address bar changing one of the [`window` properties](https://gitlab.com/ashleyconnor/adventurersclubcomic/blob/master/js/enllax.js#L73-111) used to calculate the caption position.

Source code is available here: https://gitlab.com/ashleyconnor/adventurersclubcomic

If I'm correct in my assumption. Is there an accurate way to offset the iOS address bar so there is no jump (sudden increase) in any of these values?

Comment: Not sure if this will help your debugging but if you scroll using page up and page down in Edge you also have a significant jumping issue. I'm going to guess it's likely the same issue. Probably a bug in your parallax code.

Comment: PgUp/Down works on Chrome and Safari on OSX but good to know. I've filed an issue on the project for this. Thanks.

Comment: Mind if I get a link to the issue you filed?

Comment: Filed on my project for now: https://gitlab.com/ashleyconnor/adventurersclubcomic/issues/1 - I'll add a pull request to the parent JS library once I figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo, and was able to reproduce the jitter on window resize in both Firefox and Chrome. After a few minutes of debuggine, I think the problem is actually in your index.js file.

You are completely refreshing the enllax plugin every time the windows resizes. This appears to be unnecessary.

If you remove the excess calls to the enllax function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// function enllax() {
    $('#start').enllax({
        type: 'foreground',
        ratio: 0.5,
        direction: 'vertical'
    });
//  $(window).scroll();
// };

    $('#begin').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#panel1").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

//  enllax();

    // And trigger the scroll event on resize to deal with changes
    // in the responsive layout
    $(window).on('resize', $(window).trigger('scroll'));
});
```

With that update, the jitter stops on resize in all the browsers I have installed. It remains to be tested in iOS because I don't have any Apple hardware to test it on, but I suspect it should fix the problem there as well.

Comment: Looks like that's fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)